# Why can I not add a space to the text of a HTML button with the 'contenteditable' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, element

I have a button in HTML and I want the user to be able to change the button's text when double clicking.

```
<button onclick='doStuff()' ondblclick='renameButton()' id='myButton'>Click Me</button>
```

This is my function in JavaScript:

```
function renameButton() {
  var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
  button.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
}//end renameButton
```

This function allows me to edit the button:

[image]

**Issue 1)** I cannot add a space when editing the button. The space-bar on my keyboard literally does nothing.

**Issue 2)** Is it possible to set a white background on the editable text to allow the user to see that it is editable? As far as I know, it is only possible to control the background color of the entire button element, but not the text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a span inside the button where the text is, and change the background-color of the span instead as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/msoLg3qb/

HTML

```
<button ondblclick='renameButton()' id='myButton'><span>Click Me</span></button>
```

CSS

```
span {
  background-color: white;
}
button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
function renameButton() {
  button.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to put a span kind of element to hold the text inside the button if you want to make sure SPACE is fed into the content.

On a button, space is a trigger for button press and hence can't be added in to the text with contenteditable attribute.

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/mwwj1jty/2/

HTML

```
<button onclick='doStuff()' ondblclick='renameButton()' id='myButton'><span id="myspan">Click Me</span></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function renameButton() {
  var span = document.getElementById('myspan');

  span.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  span.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}//end renameButton
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `button` element for this, as you can see that there are limitations. When a button is active, pressing the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key initiates a `click` event. To get around this, use a different element, a `span` would be perfect here.

I've also added the background color as you asked about.

Lastly, don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, etc.). That's an ancient technique that just will not die but has **[many reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead, follow modern standards and use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

```js
// Get a reference to the button
var spn = document.getElementById("myButton");

// Set up your event handlers in JavaScript, not in HTML
spn.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
spn.addEventListener("dblclick", renameButton);
spn.addEventListener("blur", saveName);

function renameButton() {
  spn.contentEditable = "true";
  spn.classList.add("edit"); 
}

function saveName(){
  spn.contentEditable = "false";
  spn.classList.remove("edit");
}

function doStuff(){
  
}
```

```css
/* Make span look like a button */
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
  color:white;
  user-select:none;
}

/* Make span feel like a button */
.button:active {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px white;
}

/* Style to add while content is editible */
.edit { 
   background-color:white; 
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<span id='myButton' class="button">Click Me</span>
```